# Is it bad to put <div> elements within the <head> tags?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, header, conditional-comments

I want to use conditional comments to make a DIV appear ONLY in browsers with IE7 or older, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>

<div id="browsernotice">
<p>You are using IE7 or less</p>
</div>

<![endif]-->
```

As far as I understand, conditional comments only work in the header.

Is this bad?

Should I rather use conditional comments to instert a stylesheet that makes an invisible DIV `visibility:visible`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to keep the content as is in the document body but instead apply a style sheet for ie that hides the div.

with css

```
    #browsernotice {
       display:none;
}
```

And call it with a conditional statement

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link href="ie7.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why someone voted my question down. I found many opinions and conflicting views out there before asking the question here.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, @Gaelen. This is not necessarily the "best" way to approach this problem because it requires an extra HTTP roundtrip to load the IE stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic!
@josh3736, would you recommend just putting the HTML for the DIV between the conditional comment tags (with its styling in the standard CSS page?)

Comment: @Gaelen, the answer--as always--is "it depends".  If you just have this one `div` to say "upgrade your browser", it's not really worth the extra stylesheet.  If you need to do a bunch of hacks to support a downlevel browser, then you probably need the extra stylesheet.

Comment: I Agree with the comments above

Comment: If you wanted to take this approach you could inline the stylesheet in the head to avoid the extra round trip.  I think this is the best version of this approach, but as josh3736's answer below explains, conditional comments do work anywhere in the body so you could just use them around the div itself if you wanted to.

Answer (score 20):

- Yes, it is [bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Document_head_elements) to put a `<div>` in your `<head>`.  It's not valid.
- [Conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx) do [work anywhere in the document](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/B6ju5/) (where did you get the idea they don't?), so just put your code at the top of your `<body>`.