# Difference between jsoup.text() and jsoup.body().text()

Tags: java, jsoup

Using Jsoup library, I'm trying to get the content(only text) from an HTML string. There are two methods which can give me the content :

```
Jsoup.parse(htmlString).body().text()
Jsoup.parse(htmlString).text()
```

I know that the first method will return only text of the body. What does the second method return? Which one is better for my usage?

**Note** : According to documentation, text method is used to set the text of the body of document

Comment: What results did you get when you tried different strings?

Comment: I got the same results for both

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each Element has the method [`text()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text--)

> public java.lang.String text() Gets the combined text of this element
>   and all its children. Whitespace is normalized and trimmed.

All elements, which can contain text-nodes (`node.nodeName()` returns #text), are [supposed to be part of the body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120573/1661938) , except for the `<title>` tag (the `<script>` and `<style>` tags have child-nodes with node name #data).

So a valid page will return the same text for `document.body().text()` and `document.text()`, as long as the title tag is not set in the head, otherwise `document.text()` will additionally contain the title text.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I updated my answer, only the `<title>` contains textnodes (#text), which are concatenated when calling `text()`

Answer (score 1):

The second line includes the text from the entire HTML document including the head, title and body, whilst the first only includes text from the body.

Comment: According to documentation, text method is used to set the text of the body of document.

Comment: @balajiprasad you can't set the text outside of body, that's why the doc says so, but you can retrieve text from head, not only from body..